# VB.NET Docking Form on Panel in Tab Page

Tags: vb.net

how to add a form in a panel inside tab page ?
i use this code to do it, but when i resize my main form, the form inside tab page doesn't auto resize.

```
Public Sub showForm(ByVal frm As MetroForm)
    Dim a As New Panel

    For i As Integer = 0 To tabPage.TabCount - 1
        If frm.Text = tabPage.TabPages(i).Text Then
            tabPage.SelectedIndex = i
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    a = New Panel
    tabPage.TabPages.Add("")
    tabPage.TabPages(tabPage.TabPages.Count - 1).Controls.Add(a)
    a.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    frm.TopLevel = False
    frm.MinimizeBox = False
    frm.MaximizeBox = False
    frm.DisplayHeader = False
    frm.AutoSize = False
    frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

    tabPage.TabPages(tabPage.TabPages.Count - 1).Text = frm.Text
    a.Visible = True
    a.Name = "pnl" & frm.Name
    a.Controls.Add(frm)
    frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    frm.Visible = True
    frm.BringToFront()

    AddHandler a.ControlRemoved, AddressOf Me.removePanel
    tabPage.SelectedIndex = tabPage.TabPages.Count - 1
    tabPage.TabPages(tabPage.TabPages.Count - 1).Name = frm.Text
End Sub
```

and to remove the tab page when form is closed :

```
Private Sub removePanel(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim a As Panel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)
    For Each obj As TabPage In tabPage.TabPages
        If obj.Name = sender.Parent.Name Then
            obj.Controls(0).Dispose() 'remove form
            tabPage.TabPages.Remove(obj) 'remove tab page
            RemoveHandler a.ControlRemoved, AddressOf Me.removePanel
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

here's the screenshot : 
[image: Before Resize]
[image: After Resize]

Comment: It seems that this custom tab control you use does not properly implement DockStyle.Fill for its tab-pages when it gets resized.  Consider filing a bug with the author.  Calling SuspendLayout *might* be a workaround.  Note that removePanel is buggy, it does not dispose the tabpage.

Comment: SuspendLsyout and ResumeLayout is not working, are there any workaround to fix this , something like resizing child form manually when i resize my main form ? or something like AddHandler frm.Resize, AddressOf childFormResize ?

Comment: I suppose you can always subscribe the Resized event instead of hoping it works automagically.  Having trouble with basic stuff is always a good reason to ditch a library, given how unlikely it is you'll get help from a site like SO.